Долгая загрузка изображений на сайте

Почему такая долгая загрузка у моего сайта? Размещён бесплатно на гитхабе. Изначально вместо webp у меня были gif, весили по несколько мегабайт и сайт грузился ещё дольше. Но без потери качества получилось сделать webp в несколько раз легче, но особо это не помогло.
Может быть у всех сайтов на гитхабе такая скорость загрузки?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! 1. Проверьте, не блокируют ли поток скрипты 2. Убедитесь, что изображения загружаются с помощью lazy loading, а не все сразу 3. Проверяли ли скорость загрузки здесь: https://pagespeed.web.dev/?hl=fr? //как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

@Dev18 спасибо, стало намного лучше

Добавьте деталей, пожалуйста, в ваш вопрос, иначе он рискует быть закрыт.
